# How to reply to a compeletly unrelated job offer mail?

Tags: job-offer

I was thinking to switch jobs and by coincident, I am getting some mail about job requirements too. One such mail is about a Senior Software Engineer while I am Database Engineer and they do seems to have a hand on my details (As they mentioned my working year experience and company).

First I thought to ignore the mail as the profile is full opposite and I am not qualified for this specific job. I am getting reminder mail about checking my interest and I was thinking about how to revert back.

I can't work on this profile but don't want to be rude and also want to check if they have requirements for me.

<sub>Note: Job is regarding full-stack development while I work as a DBA who do survival programming</sub>

Comment: 'Senior Software Engineer while I am Database Engineer'..are they really that unrelated or complete opposite?

Comment: @PagMax I work on MySql and a bit on PHP but this job profile is full stack development with nodejs and so many other fornt and back end programming skills when I am more of DBA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say, ignore them. If you specifically did not initiate the communication, and/or the solicitation is out of context, its highly probable that this is some sort of bulk emails, mostly automated, going out to maybe hundreds of recipients, expecting some reply from someone, and then, the actual communication will begin.

Unless it's of your direct interest, ignore them.

My suggestion: Check out the job postings, find out the matching jobs and reach out yourself for exact positions. Do not rely on random unsolicited communication to produce any meaningful result.

Comment: this email did specify my work experience year and company name and two followup emails also received

Comment: I guese you're in India, same place as mine and believe me, I've received more than a gazillion of these. They are bogus.

Comment: And scrapping LinkedIn profiles etc and sending email using that data is not uncommon these days.

Comment: Ohh ok. I started getting it these days only.

Answer (score 2):

**Just say you changed your mind and want to talk about whether they might have something for you**

A friend of mine recently decided that he needed a change and went back to all the recruiters he declined earlier. Most have recieved him well. Recruiters are in the business of passing candidates to companies. A large referral fee more than makes up for the initial rejection.

Comment: I didn't reject them either, just thinking how to reply

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Don't reply to unsolicited spam. It will only get worse if you do. Instead, create a separate disposable email address for job-hunting/job-prospecting.